# Using .replace function

Tags: python

I have a code with more than 2500 lines that contains several references to GIS layers. I need to replace these layers in the code for several web maps so I have to find a way to automate a find and replace function.

Following a video example, I went on and created my own version of but couldn't get it to work. So, after failing at troubleshooting and googleing I decided to replicate exactly what I see in the video and oh surprise! it turns out it doesn't for me either.

```
curseWords = ["crap", "butt", "fork"]
niceWords = ["poo", "buttox", "spoon"]
dirtySentence = "You crap, butt in fork"

def Censor(curseWords, niceWords, dirtySentence):
    for i in range(len(niceWords)):
        dirtySentence = dirtySentence.replace(curseWords[i], niceWords[i])

    return dirtySentence

print(dirtySentence)
```

I expected this code would change `dirtySentence` to `You poo, buttox in spoon` but it doesn't do it. Anyone has any idea what might be wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: `print(Censor(curseWords, niceWords, dirtySentence))`. You need to execute your function.

Comment: And indentation is a important thing in Python. You need to move the function definition one indentation left.

Comment: First,  the script has many wrong indentations. You should not indent function def block. Second, you only defined the function, not actually called it. Last, I recommend not to use a capital letter when defining a function. It does not cause a syntactic error, but a name starts with a capital letter is recommended only for classes. Use lower case characters and underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to call your defined function `Censor`. See below:

```
curseWords = ["crap", "butt", "fork"]
niceWords = ["poo", "buttox", "spoon"]
dirtySentence = "You crap, butt in fork"

def Censor(curseWords, niceWords, dirtySentence):
    for i in range(len(niceWords)):
        dirtySentence = dirtySentence.replace(curseWords[i], niceWords[i])

    return dirtySentence


dirtySentence = Censor(curseWords, niceWords, dirtySentence) # call the defined function
print(dirtySentence)
```

> **Output:** `You poo, buttox in spoon`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I was aware about Python sensitivity to indentation but I didn't realize I had them wrong. I'd marked this as the correct answer but I don't have enough achievements to do so.

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer (Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in....)