# How can I find and replace all occurrences of words in a JSON file and save the resulting JSON using python?

Tags: python, json

I have 2500-line JSON code where I need to replace several values (20 digit id's) by new ones. It's a quick find and replace and thanks to this forum I got that to work yesterday.
Now, what I noticed is that the code printed out in the python console is not proper JSON, so when I copy and paste it, it throws a lot of errors. I was trying to find a way to load the JSON file, run the find and replace and export the results to a new JSON file.

I first tried loading the JSON file with open and assigning it to a variable but when I do that the find and replace function doesn't work. So, I just assigned the raw code to a variable.
But then, when I try to write/export a JSON file it just doesn't work. I tried many solutions I found online but all of the throw errors either not finding the 'str' or the 'write' objects or that just create empty files.

The code below is an example of what I need to do. I'm not allowed to publish the actual code.

```
import string
import csv
import json
from pprint import pprint

# These values need to be replaced in the code
# 1) Original View
# 2) View Source

valuesToReplace = ["Original View",
                   "View Source"
                   ]

# Replace/change these values
newValues = ["New Original View",
             "New View Source"
             ]

data = """{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        null,
        {"id": "Quality"},
        {"id": "Pause"},
        {"id": "Mute"},
        null,
        {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
        {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
        {"id": "Copy"},
        {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
        {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
        {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
        null,
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}
"""

# If, instead, JSON file is loaded and assigned to variable, ReplaceValues throws an error
# with open(r"C:\jsonexample\codeExample.json") as dataFile:
#     data = json.load(dataFile)

def ReplaceValues(valuesToReplace, newValues, data):
    for i in range(len(newValues)):
        data = data.replace(valuesToReplace[i], newValues[i])
    return data

data = ReplaceValues(valuesToReplace, newValues, data)

pprint(data)

json.dump(data, r"C:\\jsonexample\\template\\newCode.json")
```

Comment: Be careful of code style no `camelCase` variable names without a very good reason! See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Also, isn't running a replace on a string representation of the JSON a bit risky? What happens if there is a key with the same name? What if one of the strings to replace appears as part of a larger string, like some text? Replacing the value "Original View" with "New Original View" is not the same thing as replacing "Original View" in the string "The Original View 2 with some extra stuff", but your code mixes them all!

Comment: Another thing: If I understand the effect of the `r` character correctly, then writing `r"C:\\jsonexample\\template\\newCode.json"` is self-defeating. Either you use double backslashes to escape, or you use `r` to interpret the string literally, not both.

Comment: After looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58653327/11301900), I would suggest that you take some time to really study the basics of Python, and programming as a whole, before attempting this sort of task. It's going to be difficult, unproductive, and overall really not fun otherwise.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, thanks for the suggestions. I'm still confused about when using camelCase and when not to do it. PyCharm sometimes warns me about it.  I'll check that link out. As for the risk in using a find and replace, there's a possibility but I don't know how else I could achieve this. I need to change around 40 maps and doing it manually would be so time consuming. I'd rather  do a QC on each map after running the script. Still, the values I'm changing are something like "0863c8853aaa4987b90199728ca667a0". What I wrote in the code was an example.

Comment: I was thinking you could probably use the JSON module to iterate over all the keys and values and replace what you need, right? At least then you can tell if the pattern to replace is part of a larger string or not.

Comment: I'll have to look this up because I honestly don't know how to use it. I'm new to scripting, as you've noticed, and I'm a bit overwhelmed haha. BTW, I'm in Montreal, too.

Comment: Hey don't sweat it, take your time. It's nice to see another Montrealer! If you need help or anything let me know and we'll start a chat, or find another way to communicate, so as not to flood the comments (do you have Slack? Are you more of a Discord kind of person?) Tomorrow I'll try to put together a simple string replace solution and a json manipulation solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm on Slack actually. My display name is JBuzz (I've been on yuldev for a while but just looking). Thanks again for your help. I'm going to work on this anyway so I get used to it and learn about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing opening the file in `r` and `w` mode (more info [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)). This is required even for `json.dump()` to save the file content.

Example:

```py
with open('out.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(json_data))
```

But for your case, you might not need to read it as JSON at all, as it's a generic find and all replace all instances.

Assuming your input file is like the `data` string in your question.

Try this:

```py
#replacements as key-value pairs
replacements = {
  'Original View':'New Original View', 
  'View Source':'New View Source'
  }

#Open the input file in read mode and get data as string
with open('your_file.json', 'r') as file:
  data = file.read()

#Replace all old value with new values
for old, new in replacements.items():
  data = data.replace(old, new)

#Open the output file in write mode and save
with open('output_file.json', 'w') as file:
  file.write(data)
```

Outputs:

```
{"menu": {
  "header": "SVG Viewer",
  "items": [
      {"id": "Open"},
      {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
      null,
      {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
      {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
      {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "New Original View"},
      null,
      {"id": "Quality"},
      {"id": "Pause"},
      {"id": "Mute"},
      null,
      {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
      {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
      {"id": "Copy"},
      {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
      {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
      {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
      {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "New View Source"},
      {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
      null,
      {"id": "Help"},
      {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
  ]
}}
```

Comment: Using a dictionary only to iterate over the keys and use them to access the dictionary in turn is nonsensical. Why not use a list of tuples instead? In the event a dictionary is a must, at least call `.items()' and iterate on that.